# how to add onclick listener to a gameobject in runtime In unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I hope my question is not duplicate; I have a lot of `Gameobjects` in unity.
i need to add `onclicklistener` in runtime to a game object with script...

please help.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a code that add an `EventTrigger` at runtime:

```
YourGameObject.AddComponent(typeof(EventTrigger));
EventTrigger trigger = YourGameObject.GetComponent<EventTrigger>();
EventTrigger.Entry entry = new EventTrigger.Entry();
entry.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerClick;
entry.callback.AddListener( (eventData) => { /* Your code here */ });
trigger.triggers.Add(entry);
```

Comment: While this is correct, it's worth noting that you should implement `IPointerDownHandler` in a script then attach that script to a GameObject during run-time. `EventTrigger` is known to be be slow  when attached to a GameObject especially on mobile devices.

Comment: @Programmer Thank you for pointing that out :)

Comment: Np but this answer should be known too so I up-voted to make sure that it is not deleted.

Comment: @LudovicFeltz  hi ludvic ....i use this sulotion but dont work for me

Comment: @LudovicFeltz  my code : GameObject.Find ("r1").AddComponent(typeof(EventTrigger));
  EventTrigger trigger = GameObject.Find ("r1").GetComponent<EventTrigger> ();
  EventTrigger.Entry entry = new EventTrigger.Entry ();
  entry.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerClick;
  entry.callback.AddListener ((eventData) => {Debug.Log ("on click attached");});
  trigger.triggers.Add (entry);

Comment: @LudovicFeltz I use your sulotion in a coroutine...

Comment: @Programmer  hi my brother.......please help that solution do n't work for me

Comment: @alikarimifard The code in this answer should work. The code in the duplicate answer should also work. If not, please add "EDIT" in your question and add the code that you used that did not work for you.

Comment: @EmerE please help